# Sybase: Set password for user "sa"

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I just installed Sybase Adaptive Server 16.0 SP03 in Windows and I was trying to create password for the user 'sa' by using the below command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>isql -Usa -P -SXXX2
```

But, I am unable to change the password for 'sa' and I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'XXX2':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
```

I tried to google it but in most of the places, I got the same command.Also, I didn't get any info on StackOverflow regarding the same. As I am new to Sybase so I don't have any info's regarding this.

Is there any alternate way to run this command or can I run the change the password from Interactive SQL tool? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you provide as a password for the `sa` account during the creation of the dataserver?

If you've lost/forgotten the password for the `sa` account, and you can't log in with any other security logins, then you'll have to shutdown ASE, and restart it with the `-p sa` command line option.

During startup (when using `-p sa`) ASE will print a one-line message containing the new password.

Once you've got a new password a) remove the `-p sa` from the startup script and b) consider using `sp_password` to reset the password for the `sa` account

Comment: Thank you markp for your answer. I was not providing the password in the command as I thought that the password would be "null" as it was written in the manual. But when I used: 
isql -Usa -P<password> it worked like a charm.

Comment: Many years ago the default `sa` password would have been NULL (empty); in recent years the product's been changed to eliminate this security hole by forcing the DBA to create a non-NULL `sa` password during the dataserver build; I'm guessing the manual you're using is either old, or hasn't been updated.  Anyhoo, good to hear you're able to log in.

Comment: Ahaa, thank you Mark, this information was really very helpful. Cheers 